# Integrating a two-dimensional Gaussian function with definite limits

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

I struggle with following problem. A two-dimensional Gaussian function $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2 \pi s^2} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/(2s^2)}$ is given and shall be integrated within the limits of $a=-\sqrt{2\mathrm{ln}(2)}s\,$  to  $\,b=\sqrt{2\mathrm{ln}(2)}s$ for both coordinates. These limits define the FWHM of the function.

Now, I know that for a one-dimensional Gaussian $g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} s} e^{-x^2/(2s^2)}$ one obtains $I = \int_a^b g(x) \mathrm{d}x = 0.760968$.

For the problem at hand, I thought that

$$
\int_a^b \int_a^b f(x,y) \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = \int_a^b g(x) \mathrm{d}x \int_a^b  g(y) \mathrm{d}y =  0.760968 \cdot 0.760968 = 0.57907,
$$
with rewriting $f(x,y)=g(x)\cdot g(y)$.

However, if the problem is recalculated in Polar coordidnates, I obtain a different result, namely

$$
\int_a^b \int_a^b f(x,y) \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^b \frac{1}{2 \pi s^2} e^{-r^2/(2s^2)} r \,\mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d} \phi = \int_0^b \frac{1}{s^2} e^{-r^2/(2s^2)} r \,\mathrm{d}r = 0.5.
$$

Where is the error and which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in the logic of the solution in polar coordinates.  The original expression:
$$\int_{a}^{b} \int_{a}^{b} f(x,y)\,dx\,dy $$
is integrated over a square region from $a$ to $b$ in both dimensions.

You convert this to:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{b} \frac{1}{2\pi s^2}e^{-r^2/(2s^2)}r\,dr\,d\phi$$

This is incorrect as now the integration is a circular region, centered at the origin, with radius $b$.

Converting to polar form seems inappropriate with a square region unless some other transformation is involved.

Comment: Thank you kindly!!! I completely overlooked the fact that the integration areas are different.

Comment: @GaussMan I find it often helps to sketch the region of integration when trying to transform the integral bounds